# Simple PDB Library

Tags: c++, protein-database

I am looking for a simple C++ library for extracting atom coordinates from a pdb file. Most I've come across do too much for my simple needs, making them unnecessarily complex.

Comment: I assume you're talking about protein database files here

Answer (score 3):

It has been *years* since I have used anything to do this, and I have only used python libraries. (I actually had a summer job at the PDB at Rutgers University).

I think what you want to use is OEChem for C++ (That's Open eye...there is a python library too).

The other python library I remember is pymmlib (Python Macromolecular Library). It might be available for C++ too, but I think it's proprietary software, so you would need a license.

I wish I remembered more... hope this helps. I don't think there will be a lightweight solution, unless you want to code it yourself.

Comment: Thanks, OEChem looks better than most I have found. Though the long process to obtain an academic licence is putting me off.

I've thrown in my own code to do what I want for now, but I'd prefer to find a suitable library/toolkit for reliability.

Answer (score 3):

ESBTL (Easy Structural Biology Template Library) ( http://esbtl.sourceforge.net/ ) is a fairly recent library that is probably ideal to your needs. It is very lightweight by itself (headers only), although it does depend on the Boost library, which may or not put you off.

The abstract of the paper describing it can be found here: (http://bioinformatics.oxfordjournals.org/content/26/8/1127.abstract)